# Would there be less collisions from murmurhash or from taking 64 bits from an MD5 hash if you want a 64 bit int?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

Looking at using a hashing algorithm that accepts a string and returns a 64bit signed integer value.

It doesn't have to be cryptographically sound, just provide a decent collision rate to be used as a key for distributed storage.

I'm looking at murmur hash [that seems to fit the bill](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/)

Curious how the properties of this compare to taking the first 64 bits of something like an MD5 hash.

Comment: Probably about the same (i.e. the probability of an accidental collision with either is small until the number of hashed strings approaches 2^32). But I don't actually have academic papers I can reference to back that up, it's just that AFAIK truncated MD5 and Murmur 3 are both reasonably well distributed.

Comment: Murmur will probably be faster and just as good for hash table purposes.

Comment: java7 can use Murmur hashcode for `String` in `HashMap`. It has 2 hashCode functions, one the document one `hashCode()` and murmur - `hash32()` that's package private and cached, just as the normal `hashCode()`. Keep in mind that impl. is unstable unlike the regular hashCode()

Answer (score 2):

Secure hashes - even theoretically 'broken' ones like MD5 - exhibit distribution that's indistinguishable from randomness (or else they wouldn't be secure). Thus, they're as close to perfect as it's possible to be.

Like all general purpose hash functions, murmurhash trades off correctness for speed. While it shows very good distribution characteristics for most inputs, it has its own pathological cases, such as the one [documented here](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/murmurhash2flaw), where repeated 4-byte sequences lead to collisions more often than desired.

In short: Using a secure hash function will never be worse, and will sometimes be better than using a general purpose hash. It will also be substantially slower, however.

Comment: I am not sure if the collision is applicable to murmur3 w/ proper seed values. (murmur2 should be deprecated now)

Comment: The summary is dead-on, but: `general purpose hash functions` do **not** `[trade] off correctness for speed`. There's a trade-off between *uniformity with any given input distribution* (usually unknown at function construction/selection) and speed. (Also, beware a [specific use of *perfect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) in the context of *hash functions*.)